# Edge browser window.open() size

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, window.open

[image]
The size of the Edge browser and IE browser does not match.

```
<script>
        window.open("http://bing.com","test","width=230,height=265");
</script>
```

Chrome and Firefox are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is By Design.

Minimum window width in Microsoft Edge is 320px. Chrome has a minimum width of 250px.

There is a Issue logged here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7887520/

This will be a bug if it gets approved and will be fixed in upcoming builds.